# py2exe PyQt5 "ImportError: No module named 'Qt'"

Tags: qt, py2exe, pyqt5

im trying to use py2exe (0.9.2.0) to convert a python script into an executable.

I've failed so far because py2exe does not find the module Qt:

```
C:\Users\Tobias\eclipse\workspace\pydevTest>python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe

5 missing Modules
------------------
? Qt                                  imported from __SCRIPT__
? WizardPage                          imported from __SCRIPT__
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? win32api                            imported from platform
? win32con                            imported from platform
Building 'dist\Test.exe'.
Building shared code archive 'dist\library.zip'.
Copy c:\windows\system32\python34.dll to dist
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd to dist\_hashlib.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtGui.pyd to dist\PyQt5.QtGui.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtCore.pyd to dist\PyQt5.QtCore.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd to dist\unicodedata.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_ssl.pyd to dist\_ssl.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_elementtree.pyd to dist\_elementtree.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\select.pyd to dist\select.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sip.pyd to dist\sip.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtWidgets.pyd to dist\PyQt5.QtWidgets.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd to dist\pyexpat.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_lzma.pyd to dist\_lzma.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_socket.pyd to dist\_socket.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_bz2.pyd to dist\_bz2.pyd
Copy C:\Python34\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd to dist\_ctypes.pyd
Copy DLL C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5Core.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\icudt53.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\icuuc53.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\icuin53.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5Gui.dll to dist\
Copy DLL C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt5Widgets.dll to dist\
```

My setup.py looks as follows:

```
import py2exe
from distutils.core import setup


setup(windows=["./src/Test.py"], options={"py2exe" : {"includes" : ["sip", "PyQt5.QtGui","PyQt5.QtWidgets","PyQt5.QtCore","PyQt5.QtCore"]}})
```

The script is rather simple. After getting rid of the first error, I might also help with the four other missing modules...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: adding PyQt5._qt to the includes results in a compile error. Thanks for the tipp, but it seems not to solve the problem in my case.

Comment: sometime importing missing modules in setup.py helps. what happens if you import PtQt5?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the following dlls:

> C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcp100.dll
>
> C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcr100.dll
>
> C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll

somethings like this:

```
data_files = (
    ('', glob(r'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcp100.dll')),
    ('', glob(r'C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcr100.dll')),
    ('platforms', glob(r'C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll')),
),
```

Comment: Thanks your answer.-The porblem were illegal imports. Python allows "from Qt import xxx" but py2exe can't resolve it. Changing the imports to "from PyQt5.Qt import xxx", the problem was solved. But the two dlls you are mentioning are missing as well. So thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the previous answer did not work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37622355/7426109

(and I have different versions)

What did work on the other hand is to add this to your path: "**C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin**".

---

### My temporary fix:

You copy the "Qt" ("**C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt**") folder to "dist", and use a batch script to add "**.dist\Qt\bin**" to PATH in the current CMD window. (of course, this is not perfect, but at least can be executed on another machine)

---

### Info

Windows 10 x64, Python 3.8.6 x32, PyQt5==5.15.1, py2exe==0.10.0.2