# Exception: Python.Runtime not found in pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe

I have used pyinstaller many times before but I have never faced such issues
I am facing issues while converting .py to .exe using pyinstaller 
What I have tried
I have installed pythonnet and opened the directory where pythonnet is stored but i could not find any dll file

I am using the following command

```
PyInstaller app.py --noconsole --icon=./images/Source.​ico
```

entire Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ADMIN.DESKTOP-USLQ9P3\Desktop\jarvis\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    PyInstaller.__main__.run([
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN.DESKTOP-USLQ9P3\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN.DESKTOP-USLQ9P3\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN.DESKTOP-USLQ9P3\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 725, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN.DESKTOP-USLQ9P3\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 672, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN.DESKTOP-USLQ9P3\Desktop\jarvis\app.spec", line 6, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['app.py'],
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN.DESKTOP-USLQ9P3\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN.DESKTOP-USLQ9P3\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__       
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN.DESKTOP-USLQ9P3\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 420, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks()
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN.DESKTOP-USLQ9P3\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 367, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN.DESKTOP-USLQ9P3\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 447, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN.DESKTOP-USLQ9P3\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 408, in _load_hook_module       
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN.DESKTOP-USLQ9P3\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 598, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 462, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 962, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 787, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN.DESKTOP-USLQ9P3\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks\hook-clr.py", line 40, in <module>
    raise Exception(pyruntime + ' not found')
Exception: Python.Runtime not found
```

I have also install pythonnet but it is still not working neither can I find the dll

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyinstaller & pandas: Python.Runtime not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664569/pyinstaller-pandas-python-runtime-not-found)

Comment: I have install pythonnet as said there but the dll is still missing in the directory they are saying it is present

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I have had a lot of issues with pyinstaller myself in the past year. At this point I have the process perfected that I almost never have issues anymore. The key for me has been:

1. Do not use virtual environments (venv). I use a separate older computer specifically for pyinstaller. The computer only has basic python, pycharm and the libraries I need for my build installed to site packages. I install everything globally. I remove libraries I do not need.
2. If a library causes problems like you describe, try installing an older versio of said library.

To follow up:

Using pycharm does not work or pycharm in general does not work?

What I would recommend you do is what I do on a fresh computer:

0. Make sure you know which libraries your project requires. You could generate a requirements file: [Automatically create requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684375/automatically-create-requirements-txt)
1. Uninstall python / anaconda from your computer completely incl all libs.
2. Reinstall python (not anaconda as it has way to many libraries) and click yes if installer asks you to add to path. Install pycharm community edition if you do not have it.
3. Install pyinstaller and other libs you need, but install them globally! I recommend using pycharm. Settings>yourproject>python interpreter>little plus icon>libraries you need. IMPORTANT: CHOOSE TO INSTALL TO SITE PACKAGE DIRECTORY: [image]

4. Go to terminal in pycharm and type: pyinstaller --onefile my_python_file.py
5. You should now get an .exe file. in a dist folder in the directory of your file.

NOTE: the above should not be necessary and pyinstaller can work with virtual environments, but I have found it to be the most reliable way to use pyinstaller.

Comment: can you recommend some other method to do so? I dont have another machine. Just a doubt :)

Comment: Are you using pycharm?

Comment: What exactly does not work? I updated my answer for you.

Comment: Also, try adding a missing dll file to your project folder and see if that helps.

Comment: I have tried everything that you mentioned in your answer still nothing

Comment: sorry to hear that. How far did you get? Where does it go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [`py2exe`](https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/). This program also bundles python programs into .exe files, and I have used it for one of my games. To install this program, simply type into the command line:

```
python -m pip install py2exe
```

For more resources on py2exe, check out these links:

- http://www.py2exe.org/
- https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe

Comment: I have tried it doesn't work because I am using pyqt5 and it is not supported bt py2exe

Comment: Try looking at this post about PyQt5 and py2exe:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334722/py2exe-pyqt5-importerror-no-module-named-qt

Comment: Maybe try using another program called cx_Freeze. See more at https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You should reinstall python and add it to your path, that might help you. There are lot of videos online you can refer to.